# How to let users upload a file to my server allowing them to re-download that file with an appended string

Tags: php, database, api

I am building a very basic site for an online MMO PC Game (Note: Game has a built in API). I need the ability to allow users to upload a "character settings" file from their game settings directory on their PC to my web server. Once the file is uploaded they need to be able to modify the file name, to apply them to another character on the server, and to re-download the files.

Example: I have a character named Tom. Each character has two settings files associated with it:

- core_user_1234567.dat
- core_char_12345678.dat files

I have another character named Jerry. I want to set him up with the same exact settings as Tom. To do this I want to upload Tom's settings files to the web server, input Jerry's `userID` and `characterID` values into a form, and re-download the files with those values appended while removing the old values from the uploaded file names. This essentially replaces the `core_user_"this".dat` to `core_user_"that".dat`.

The steps I need to complete in order to get the functionality I require for the app to work.

Step 1.) The user obtains the **UserID** and **CharacterID** for Tom from the games server by calling the games API for that character. (User enters his API key into a form and submits. This will return the two values to be displayed in the browser. This is simply a reference call so i can display the values to the user in the browser so that the user knows which two settings files correspond to the character he is trying to clone (in this case Tom). There may be many sets of settings files already in the folder. (This step I can achieve already).

Step 2.) Once the user knows which two settings files belong to Tom the user then locates and uploads Toms settings files to the webserver.

Step 3.) Now, once the files are on the server the user needs to obtain the **userID** and **characterID** for Jerry. I do the same thing as in Step 1. Make an API call and display the returned value to the browser so the user knows the values.

Step 4.) The user can then insert the values into a form and submit it. Once submitted the values are appended onto the settings files that are temporarily being stored on the server and a download link is generated.

Step 5.) User downloads the new settings files to the settings directory and it's done. Jerry now has the same settings files as Tom.

EDIT: My inquiry is regarding step 2 and step 5. The PHP side of things. How does one write this simple upload script. Upload the file, pass in a string to the file name replacing everything after the second _ and before the .dat, then generate the download link? core_user_"replacethisstring".dat

Comment: This is all relatively straightforward programming. What exactly are you stuck with, where are you in the process? Are you having a question about how to do a specific step?

Comment: Sounds like you've designed it quite thoroughly. Break down the remaining steps, and tackle them in order. Bear in mind that Stack Overflow is not like other programming sites: the posting guidelines here are rather tighter, to try to avoid questions that have either very broad or discursive answers.

Comment: Yes. The PHP Part. I know it's a very simple task, or at least I believe it is from looking at some sample code. I am newish to PHP but not to new. Trying to figure out how to achieve step 2 and step 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still rather broad, but I'll happily offer some pointers. It seems the bit you need some help with is the PHP code. Here are the broad steps I think you need:

- A login/logout system to identify individual users
- A profile page for users to specify their user and character IDs
- A file upload form (e.g. for Tom)
- A download form (e.g. for Jerry), in which Jerry's userID and characterID are specified
- A system to modify uploaded files

So, Tom logs in, and uploads his two files using the upload form. They are stored in a folder named after his user ID, so they don't get mixed up with anyone else's files. One is called "core_user" and the other is called "core_char" (since longer suffixes are redundant here).

Jerry now logs in. He inputs his own "userID" and "characterID" into the download form. Does he also need to specify that he wishes to clone Tom's files, and not Road Runner's? If so, he does that at this stage. The page then shows him two download links, one for each file.

When he clicks on each, they are dynamically generated from the target user, with the modifications based on the downloader's own details. This could additionally be stored as  a file for this user, but it is not necessary at this stage. To do this step, read the file using `file_get_contents`, modify it using string manipulation functions, and then echo it to the browser. If you use the appropriate headers, it will appear as a downloadable file, rather than a text document.

It is arguable that Jerry does not need to specify his userID and characterID in the download form, since if he has logged in, these can be obtained from his profile.

You'll notice that I've not mentioned an API here - I'm not entirely sure what that is in your context, but it may be a distraction in the first cut. Get the simplest possible version working first.

So, here the problem is broken down a great deal more. If you find a sub-problem insurmountable, then it is possible it needs to be broken down again, until each thing is a PHP call or an HTML form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very informative and was able to perform the task using your solutions. =)

Comment: @user2833068: Great stuff, pleased it was of help! `:)`